# pyqtgraph: plot with a similar functionality as matplotlib drawstyle

Tags: python, plot, pyqtgraph

Is there any possibility within **pyqtgraph** to get the **blue graph** instead of the red one that is standard method in matplotlib AND pyqtgraph in the following matplotlib example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0,1,0.1)
y = [0,0,0,2,2,8,9,2,0,0]

plt.plot(x,y,color='red',drawstyle='standard')
plt.plot(x,y,color='blue',drawstyle='steps-post')

plt.show()
```

So far I did not find a way to create the blue graph in pyqtgraph with the given data x and y.

Thanks a lot
Regards
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is described in the pyqtgraph 'histogram' example. This is the translation:

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(0,1,0.1)
y = [0,0,0,2,2,8,9,2,0,0]
print len(x), len(y)

plt = pg.plot(x,y,pen='r')
curve2 = pg.PlotCurveItem(x,y[:-1],pen='b',stepMode=True)
plt.addItem(curve2)
```