# Is there a way to reproduce matplotlib's drawstyle='mid' functionality in pyqtgraph?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, pyqtgraph

I'm trying to reproduce the example of matplotlib found [here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/step_demo.html).
I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17722583/pyqtgraph-plot-with-a-similar-functionality-as-matplotlib-drawstyle) but it doesn't cover the case for `drawstyle='mid'`
I assumed `stepMode='center'` would do the trick but I can't seem to get the same behavior as `drawstyle='mid'`.
Any help? Is it even possible?

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(14)
y = np.sin(x / 2)


plt = pg.plot(x, y+2, pen='blue', stepMode='left')
plt.addItem(pg.PlotDataItem(x, y+2, pen='grey', symbol='o'))

plt.addItem(pg.PlotDataItem(x, y[:-1]+1, pen='orange', stepMode='center'))
plt.addItem(pg.PlotDataItem(x, y+1, pen='grey', symbol='o'))

plt.addItem(pg.PlotDataItem(x, y, pen='green', stepMode='right'))
plt.addItem(pg.PlotDataItem(x, y, pen='grey', symbol='o'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find an implicit way of doing this like in matplotlib but here is a fix if anyone is interested.

```
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(14)
y = np.sin(x / 2)

dx = x[1] - x[0]
# Define a new x slightly offset by dx/2
# you have to go to 2*dx to get the right side edge of the final bin
# because len(x2) needs to be len(y)+1 with stepMode='center'
x2 = np.arange(0, x[-1]+2*dx, dx) - dx/2

plt = pg.plot(x, y+2, pen='blue', stepMode='left')
plt.addItem(pg.PlotDataItem(x, y+2, pen='grey', symbol='o'))

plt.addItem(pg.PlotDataItem(x2, y+1, pen='orange', stepMode='center'))
plt.addItem(pg.PlotDataItem(x, y+1, pen='grey', symbol='o'))

plt.addItem(pg.PlotDataItem(x, y, pen='green', stepMode='right'))
plt.addItem(pg.PlotDataItem(x, y, pen='grey', symbol='o'))
```

Which yields this:
[image: img_correct]